# Show print preview in web page with margins, watermark and header applied

Tags: html, angular, printing, wysiwyg, preview

I am trying to show a preview of a HTML content with page size, margins, header-footer and watermark applied. I had a fair success with using jsPDF so that I can show the preview before it gets converted to PDF in a new tab.

Instead I would like to have a live preview kind of work. The following is the abstracted form of the requirement where I have to HTML editors and the content from each are combined and shown preview like this.
[image]

Any change applied can be previewed by pressing the "Refresh" button on top including the page settings.

Can anyone help me in pointing to some plugin with which I could achieve the same? ASP .Net and Angular are the environment and would be more than happy to respond to any clarifications raised.

I can work on developing this with help of a developer but both of us at present lack the know-how. Any pointers in suggested approach is enough.

Answer (score 0):

Show the codes, so anyone can see what's wrong with the code and why the relations are not connected with the HTML live show pdf.